# Error retrieving image from URL or bad URL with webContentLink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

My application is trying to insert a bunch of images to google drive sheet using google app script.
The script method is calling from a Rails app as following:

```
@app_script.run_script(script_id, request)
```

The script method is trying to fetch the image through the id and insert it to the sheet.

```
var srcfile = DriveApp.getFileById(object.image_file_id);
srcfile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
var image = SpreadsheetApp.openById(object.spreadsheet_id).getSheetByName(object.sheet_name).insertImage(Drive.Files.get(srcfile.getId()).webContentLink, object.column, object.row);
```

The problem is coming intermittently with the response error from google script:

```
Exception: Error retrieving image from URL or bad URL: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1yZULGInEcjQ_nA4j_Nmy6F2e3JcYnLFP&export=download
```

Note that I can download the image successful if I just copy the link and paste it to browser.
The image file and its parent folder are public share.
It seem hard to detect the problem when it does not always happen.

For those who concern about my script, it is [here](https://script.google.com/a/vectorgroup.vn/d/1fozmpJ6rXNzgTN_uV4jFj_BJJJCLmgKMC0m1TgYPVhYUo5YqTmv7LfHC/edit?usp=drive_web)

Answer (score 3):

> Exception: Error retrieving image from URL or bad URL

This is a common error message when the image size is too big.

See [here](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/9414d22de2ff30216269ca7be4bce462) for more information.

You need to recuce the image size - either manually or programmatically - before inserting.

**UPDATE**

If the suggestion above does not solve your issue, implement the following workaround:

Instead of inserting the image by its `webContentLink` with the method [insertImage(url, column, row)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageurl,-column,-row) , use the method [insertImage(blobSource, column, row)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageblobsource,-column,-row):

`var image = SpreadsheetApp.SpreadsheetApp.openById(object.spreadsheet_id).getSheetByName(object.sheet_name).insertImage(DriveApp.getFileById(srcfile.getId()).getBlob(), object.column, object.row);`

This should solve the issue.

Comment: No I can observe the issue even image size is small enough.

Comment: What is the image type? Is it a thumbnail? And the image size?

Comment: It is png/jpg image, an example of the error log: Exception: Error retrieving image from URL or bad URL: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1vTy5f0HBhpIKKkBNVkhgyZoOwvhD312k&export=download. It is only 854 × 501

Comment: I can also reproduce the issue this morning. While I am not quite sure what the reason for the error is (maybe a bug from Google's side?), there is a workaround - I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes please that is great if you could provide a workaround. I guess the issue comes from Google side also. This morning the issue happened frequently.

Comment: Can you explain me why the issue can be avoided by using blobSource?

Comment: I can't. I can only suspect that there is some bug / outage with the insertImage(url, column, row) method, while insertImage(blobSource, column, row) works as intended. Consider filing a bug on Google's Issue Tracker.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I would accept it as an answer. But there is a reason I don not want to use blobSource since it needs to be ensure the image size limit while I want to achieve the best quality when inserting. It seems  insertImage(url, column, row) can be success even if the file size exceeds the limit.

Comment: I temporarily received the same error like you, but now it works again! It must have been some temporarily issue from Google's side. I hope for you it also works again. Otherwise, `Drive.Files.get(srcfile.getId()).thumbnailLink` also works if this is a suitable solution for you.

Comment: Yes thanks for your information. I know it is a temporary issue but it quite happens sometimes not only today. That might be better to submit the issue to Google as you said.

Comment: Are you facing the issue when you run script directly from script editor?